# anchorScroll not working, going to top of page

Tags: angularjs, anchor-scroll

I have below code

```
$scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
     alog($location.hash());
     var toScrollId = "anchor" + id;
     if($location.hash() !== toScrollId){
       alog(" hash is not equal")
       $location.hash(toScrollId);
     }else{
      alog(" hash is equal")
       $anchorScroll();
     }
};
```

and html looks like

```
<button ng-click="scrollTo(raceid)">GO TO THIS</button>

<div ng-repeat="race in races" id="{{ 'anchor' + race.raceId}}">
</div>
```

But scroll always goes to top of page. Anything i am doing wrongly?

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your `ng-repeat` is assigning the `id` to the parent element (in this case, the `races` div) you might need to modify that first:

```
<div ng-repeat="race in races" id="races">
    <div id="{{ 'anchor' + race.raceId }}">Some race</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried ur code also. But its taking me to top of page. Any html or anything i need to take of explicitly??